# Using props to initially set state

Tags: reactjs

I've been doing some research tonight surrounding the topic of using props to set the initial state of a component, and I've come across people arguing both sides. My question, therefore has two parts.

1) Is what I am doing considered the anti-pattern? From what I can tell it is not -- according to [this article](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e)  If so, what specifically is wrong with it?

2) Is there another way I could re-write this logic without using props to set the state?

**Parent Component:**

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      todos: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ todos: response.data })
    });
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.todos){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {
              this.state.todos.map((todo, i) => {
                return (
                  <Todo todo={todo} key={i}/>
                )
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class Todo extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var { title, completed, userId } = this.props.todo;
    this.state = { title, completed, userId }
  }
  changeCompletion = () => {
    this.setState({completed: !this.state.completed})
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div className={"card card-inverse text-center " + (this.state.completed ? 'card-success' : 'card-danger')}>
          <div className="card-block">
            <blockquote className="card-blockquote">
              <p>{ this.state.title }</p>
            </blockquote>
            <button onClick={this.changeCompletion} className={"btn btn-sm " + (this.state.completed ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-success')}>{ this.state.completed ? 'incomplete' : 'complete'} </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Is what I am doing considered the anti-pattern?** - ***Maybe, YES***

The problem is the constructor of your child component only runs once across multiple renders. If you use `setState()` in your child component to re-render the constructor won't run again thus the props and the state are out of sync which is the "multiple sources of truth" problem the article mentions.

If you re-render your parent component (either through state change, props change, or `this.forceUpdate()`), you child component's constructor won't re-execute. That is, React does this to improve performance internally, you can use `console.log()` to investigate the component's life-cycles.

Usually, if I bump into your situation, I will add a life-cycle method called `ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and use the `nextProps` there to re-initiate the state. Although it is not the perfect solution because other developers may modify the props in the component and we are back at the "multiple sources of truth" problem. You need to tell or educate other developers in your project that they are not allowed to modify props directly or indirectly in the component but even though, they may forget sometimes. But at least adding the life-cycle method does improve the situation.

**2. Is there another way I could re-write this logic without using props to set the state?**

You can try this approach: Basically, you expose a callback in child component's props and in the parent component, you execute it to trigger re-render of the parent component which in turn trigger re-render of all child components which is what we want.

And keep in mind that, when React re-renders all child components, it does not destroy then re-create all of them thus their `constructor` won't re-execute. Only their life-cycle method `ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` will be executed.

**Parent Component:**

```
<Todo todo={todo} key={i} onChangeCompletionCallback={() => {
    let clonedState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    clonedState.todos[i].completed = !clonedState.todos[i].completed;
    this.setState(clonedState);
}}/>
```

**Child Component**

```
changeCompletion = () => {
    this.props.onChangeCompletionCallback();
}
```

---

> *One follow-up question, In this particular example, since there are
>   200 todos being rendered, and I'm only changing the completion status
>   one at a time, would this be an instance where manually configuring
>   the shouldComponentUpdate() function could be the difference of 1
>   render versus 200? Is it inherently bad to render all 200 todos?*

Let's first clarify the `render` term. There are 2 kinds of `render` in React:

- Real DOM `render`: **slow**
- Virtual DOM `render`: (is designed to be) **fast**

Now, if you Real DOM `render` 200 todos, that is definitely bad. But if you Virtual DOM `render` 200 todos, that depends. But most of the case, it will be fast.

When you `render` a component via `props change`, `state change` or `this.forceUpdate()`, you are doing a Virtual DOM `render`. After that,

1. React uses a diffing algorithm to compare the Real DOM and the
   Virtual DOM then extract the differences.
2. React does a Real DOM `render` based on the differences above. It only
   Real DOM `renders` what is needed.

So I don't think manually configuring the `shouldComponentUpdate(...)` life-cycle method will help much in this case. It looks like you saved 199 Virtual DOM `renders` but actually you are wasting your effort.

`this.setState(...)` is asynchronous. That means whenever you call `this.setState(...)` the Virtual DOM `render` does not happen immediately. React will attempt to batch multiple Virtual DOM `renders` in one big Virtual DOM `render`. So even if you issue 199 virtual DOM `renders`, react is smart enough to batch them together so only 1 virtual DOM `render` will happen. Doing it manually in `shouldComponentUpdate(...)` is not necessary.

And finally, my explanation is theoretically (based on the docs). If you take performance optimization problem seriously, you may need to do investigation to get more solid information (fact & figures). But at least, my theoretical explanation could give you some good start, I hope.

Comment: Great explanation! Your implementation worked perfectly. I hadn't considered using a callback, but can see that being a valuable tool moving forward. One follow-up question, In this particular example, since there are 200 todos being rendered, and I'm only changing the completion status one at a time, would this be an instance where manually configuring the shouldComponentUpdate() function could be the difference of 1 render versus 200? Is it inherently _bad_ to render all 200 todos?

Comment: The answer was too big to fit in a comment thus I updated my answer above. Please take a look.

Comment: Got it. I think I'm probably in the clear. I'll do some more digging to make sure but I really appreciate your help!